# Beacon scan in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, beacon, eddystone

I'm trying to scan Beacon device in objective c. I'm having multiple brand `beacon` (estimote,gimbal and etc). I wont to go to use them api. I want unique for objective c to detect the beacon device.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a tutorial for ranging beacons in Objective C here:

http://mentormate.com/blog/beacon-ranging-ios/